# Subst a string reverse to the last slash

Tags: php, substr

Hello. I have a string with a path. I do not need the whole path. Is it possible to `substr` to a last slash ? Based on the code below, I dont need the `modelname`.

Thanks for any hints you can give.

```
$path = userdir/modeldir/modelname
```

Comment: http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Bit confused so what do you want from the string?

Comment: i need the path without modelname.
to write a texture inside the path userdir/modeldir/texturefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exploding the array by using the slash as a delimiter?

```
$pathArray = explode('/', $path);
```

That should give you the entire folder tree as an array.

For further information visit: http://www.php.net/explode

Comment: Thank you very much. Its exact what i needed

Answer (score 1):

Bit confused,

do you want `modelname`? ok then use [`basename()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) <kbd>**[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eOJBB5)**</kbd>

```
echo basename('userdir/modeldir/modelname'); //modelname
```

Or do you want `userdir/modeldir`? ok then use [`dirname()`](https://www.php.net/dirname) <kbd>**[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XgyVar)**</kbd>

```
echo dirname('userdir/modeldir/modelname/'); //userdir/modeldir
```

Comment: i needed only the path without the modelname

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
$address = 'userdir/modeldir/modelname';
$a=explode("/",$address);
echo $a[2];
```

Comment: i dont need in the output the modelname. i need only the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = 'userdir/modeldir/modelname';
$arr = explode('/', $path);
echo $arr[count($arr) - 1]; // Will output modelname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$path = 'userdir/modeldir/modelname';
$pathArray = explode('/', $path);
array_pop($pathArray);
$path = implode('/', $pathArray);
?>
```

Or, if you want it in a nice function:

```
<?php
function removeLast($path, $delim = '/') {
    $pathArray = explode($delim, $path);
    if (count($pathArray) == 1) return $pathArray[0];
    array_pop($pathArray);
    return implode($delim, $pathArray);
}

echo removeLast('userdir/modeldir/modelname');
?>
```